# how to insert selected columns from a very large pipe delimited text/csv file to mysql using LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: php, mysql

There is a similar question already but I would like to know how to accomplish this for very large data sets.

The @dummy method etc will be take very long.

Also, what should I do if the column names are different in the spreadsheet and the table?

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/actor.tsv'
REPLACE INTO TABLE actor
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(@f1, @f2, @f3)
SET first_name = @f1, last_name = @f3
```

**UPDATE**. If number of fields is big use this script to generate the LOAD command:

```
echo -n "LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/actor.tsv'
REPLACE INTO TABLE actor
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\\t'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
("
comma=""
for i in `seq 300`
do
    echo -n "$comma @f$i"
    comma=","
done
echo ")"
echo "SET first_name = @f1, last_name = @f3"
```

Comment: Should (@f1, @f2, @f3) include all columns in the file?

Comment: I don't know. I would test. My guess would be MySQL will ignore the rest of the columns

Comment: Does f1, f2 etc represent the column name or column number?

Comment: f1, f2, f3 are just variables names. They can be any.
first_name, last_name are column names in the table

Comment: I don't think this is addressing my issue since I want to target only specific columns in the text/csv file

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the problem? You have let's say 5 columns in the dump. And want to insert column 2 and 4 into a table. Right?

Comment: Then I insist on the solution. You list all five columns in variables f1-f5 and use f2 and f4 for assignment.

Comment: That's exactly my point .. Is there a way to only select the columns I want instead of listing all columns because there are 300 columns in the file

Comment: So what? Generate the command : for i in \`seq 300\`; do echo -n ", f$i"; done

Comment: Can you ellaborate please

Comment: A follow up question .. Is there a way to automate this process in mysql ? Meaning .. schedule it to pull the csv file once every week?